# Fenwick tree(BIT). Find the smallest index with given cumulative frequency in O(logN)

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search, fenwick-tree, binary-indexed-tree

let's say I have a BIT(Fenwick Tree) with non-negative values and I want to find the smallest index in it for given cumulative frequency in O(logN).

*Now, I can do it O(log^2(N)) like this.*

```
int l = 0, r = n;
while(l < r) {
    int midd = l + (r-l)/2;
    if (get_sum(BIT, midd+1) < given_sum)
        l = midd+1;
    else
        r = midd;
}
return midd + 1;
```

I know that we can find any of index or the greatest index in O(logN) as described [here](https://www.topcoder.com/community/competitive-programming/tutorials/binary-indexed-trees/), so expect to find the lowest with the same time complexity as well.
The way the tree is implemented is a common one.

```
vector<int> BIT(n+1);
void update(vector<int> &BIT, int idx, int delta){
    for(int i = idx; i < BIT.size(); i +=(i&-i))
        BIT[i] += delta;
}
int get_sum(vector<int>& BIT, int idx){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = idx; i > 0; i-=(i&-i))
        sum += BIT[i];
    return sum;
}
```

Hope for your help:)

Comment: What if there is no such frequency in the tree? Do you want lower bound?

Comment: If there is no such frequency, you can either return -1 or lower bound. 
Lower bound is good as well.

Comment: I can share my implementation of a lower bound for a tree with 0-based indexing. Will it help?

Comment: Yes, I believe in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my implementation of a `lower_bound`-like function for a Fenwick tree with 0-based indexing:

```
std::size_t lower_bound(int value) const
{
    std::size_t index = 0;
    for (auto mask = msb_size_mask(); mask != 0; mask >>= 1)
    {
        const auto k = mask + index - 1;
        if (k < data.size() && data[k] < value)
        {
            value -= data[k];
            index += mask;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

`data` is the underlying `std::vector<int>`. The helper function `msb_size_mask()` returns the minimum size of a Fenwick tree such that the underlying binary tree is perfect, i.e. it returns `2^k` if `data.size()` is in the range `(2^{k-1}, 2^k]`. In C++20, this is exactly what [`std::bit_ceil()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_ceil) does.

Here is the update function:

```
void add(std::size_t index, int value)
{
    for (; index < data.size(); index |= index + 1)
        data[index] += value;
}
```

The complete code can be found [here](https://github.com/eugnsp/eslib/blob/master/include/esk/fenwick_tree.hpp).